# Can't access server from wireless LAN address on windows

Tags: windows, ip, lan

I'm running a super simple http server on port 9000. I can access it fine via `http://localhost:9000`, but when I try to access it on the same port 9000 via my IP address (which I get from doing an `ipconfig` and taking the IPv4 Address from "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi") from the same machine (the one that's running the server), the server can't be found. I've turned off both my public and private firewall to test this.

I've also tried adding a "virtual server" port forwarding in my router, which I don't think I should have to do, but it didn't help.

What could be preventing my computer from finding its own server on its LAN IP address? My end-goal is to be able to access this server from my phone connected to the wifi, but this is the first step.

I'm running windows 8.1.

By popular demand, here's the server I'm running via node.js:

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200)
    response.write("what")
    response.end()
}).listen(9000)
```

Comment: Please specify which software you are using, your router, and if the server has a static or dynamic ip.

Comment: You say **"'I'm running a super simple http server on port 9000"**. `1.` What's the internal IP address of that server? You say **"when I try to access it on the same port 9000 via my IP address"**. `2.` What's the internal IP address of that machine? I assume you're running this all on your local network and not across the Internet. Answer those questions please.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow I'm running a simple node.js server. Whether or not my IP address is static or dynmic shouldn't matter - its static on the time-scales we're talking about. My LAN IP address hasn't changed in months.

Comment: @Walmart I'm not giving you my IP address. And I already mentioned in my question that I'm trying to access the server from the same machine that's running it.

Comment: The server _service_ itself can also specify who it listens to. What is the webserver software you are running? Check that it is set to allow external connections. If you try opening a socket to port 9000, what do you get for an error? _Refused_? Nothing is listening. _Timeout_? Probably firewall.

Comment: @MattClark Its not. I just updated my post with the full server code.

Comment: If you want help, read _my_ comment. I posted before you edited. I never said you had an issue starting the server. You code disproves one of my points however. If you try establishing a connection via IP, you get an error; _what is that error_? Refused? Or Timeout?

Comment: What router do you have, it's entirely possible the router is blocking the connection.

Comment: @MattClark I'm tired and cranky and didn't give you the benefit of the doubt while misinterpreting your comment. I appologize. In any case, the error I get when trying to access it in chrome is "This site can't be reached" with either ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED or ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED  or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE which I verified all happen when I'm not running the server at all too - so basically its not finding it.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow Its a TP-LINK AC1750. Why would my router block anything over its LAN? Its whole purpose is to direct traffic over the LAN right?

Comment: No worries, but be patient with people who are _trying to help_. Read, and reread before commenting. All of these imply different things, and come at different phases in the connection cycle. Can you please, start the server, try refreshing chrome _once_, and responding with the error you see when everything is in a known state. _EMPTY_RESPONSE_ actually means you established the connection, but your application sent no data back to the web browser.

Comment: @BT some routers block inter connectivity for security, and these days most routers are combinations of a gateway, a switch, and a firewall.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow also makes a good point, check and see if you have `AP Isolation` enabled on your router. This will disallow intercommunication between devices on the network.

Comment: Here is the user manual for your router see page 58 on the PDF. http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/Archer_C7_V1_UG.pdf

Comment: @MattClark Starting the server fresh, refreshing http://<my LAN IP>:9000 gives me ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. About the other errors, it is confusing that chrome does that. But like I mentioned, whether or not I'm running the server, chrome is giving me back all 4 of those errors in some attempts to load the page. So I have to assume its weird chrome behavior.

Comment: Lets confirm are we attempting to access this server via its lan IP from a different machine or the same one?

Comment: @CharlesLudlow From the same machine - everything I'm doing is on one machine.

Comment: @MattClark and CharlesLudlow, AP Isolation was not enabled. Thanks for the doc reference, made it easy to find that option.

Comment: Your welcome @BT Do you have any other firewall or antivirus / malware type programs on the machine? Besides of course Windows Firewall and Windows Defender?

Comment: A _CONNECTION_RESET_ means that you are actually establishing a TCP connection to the server ( node ) - but the server is closing the socket abruptly. Trying to reproduce, hang tight.

Comment: @MattClark and BT You may also want to try Firefox or even IE.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow I don't have any other firewall or antivirus installed other than what came in a fresh windows install. And I've disabled windows firewall (both "private" and "public") while I try to figure this out

Comment: This may seem silly but run "NetSh Advfirewall set allprofiles state off" and reboot, it is possible that Windows didn't completely disable its firewall.

Comment: Ohhhhh kayyy, I figured it out. What I forgot about was that I have a vagrant VM running that exposes some ports, including 9000. Something about how it handles that must be screwing up the ability to respond on that port from outside. Thanks for your  Help guys! Feel free to write up some answers I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have nothing else occupying the port in question. This could include other software, VM's, or Windows its self. Also add a port exception in Windows Firewall and turn it back on for security.

```
netsh advfirewall set allrprofiles state on

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Name" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9000

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Name" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9000
```

Replace Name with what you want to call it.